# PHP Chart Library that supports SWF export

Tags: php, charts, export

Is there any open source PHP Charting Library that supports exporting of interactive graphs, that allow zooming and panning offline/in Powerpoint? I have gone through various libraries, but don't seem to find any such. AnyChart looked promising with its interactive pdf but doesn't exactly fit my requirements.

I am currently working on a intranet website that automates data handling. As of now I am held up at the generation of a timeline-like graph that shows actions taken in the company to combat customers complaints. So far, employees spend hundreds of man hours manually creating these graphs for each vehicle (its an automobile company), which were then put in Powerpoint presentations for senior management.

I have a SQL database with the required data, and using PHP for server-side scripting.

Comment: Have you had a look at oomfo.com ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using JPGraph

JPGraph renders the graph as image using GD library, the idea is you can show your graphs on  the page and then you can export the page as HTML or PDF  or xls using api to include it in your presentation files

Check the JPGraph link here

http://jpgraph.net/

Comment: I currently use [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) for the same. I wanted to have an interactive graph, exportable, since the number of actions taken is high and spread over a wide range of time, and it would be easier to show in the presentation.